# How do I send gravity form fields to MixPanel

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, mixpanel

I have a gravity form in my word press site with a number of fields (e.g name, company, email etc). When the gravity form is submitted I need it to push the field value's into Mix Panel and create a new profile.

How can I get this to work. Here's the logic i need below

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_after_submission', function(event, formId){
    mixpanel.identify("GravityformID");
    mixpanel.people.set({
    "$first_name": "GravityformName",
    "$company": "GravityformCompany",
    "$email": "Gravityformemail",
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `gform_after_submission` is a filter which runs in the server. You need to declare the filter and create a php function in your theme's `funtions.php` file

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoR. I'll give it a go